# How to check if a function is an attribute of a list?

Tags: python, attributes

So, I'm trying to check if a function is an attribute of a list. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do it. I tried this code:

```
def test():
    return "test"

list = [test]

if hasattr(list, test):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

but that gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if hasattr(list, test):
TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

I would like to know a working way, so if you know how, please tell me.

Comment: `if test in list:`? The contents of a list aren't its attributes, by the way, and `list` is a terrible name for a list as it shadows the built-in.

Answer (score 2):

The question you asked is how to stop `hasattr()` giving you a TypeError. The way to fix it is in the error message: *attribute name must be a string*. So if you do this, you will not get an error message, but you also won't get the answer you are expecting:

```
>>> hasattr(list,'test')
False
```

That is because `test` is an *element* of the list, not an attribute of the list. If, on the other hand, you do this:

```
>>> hasattr(list,'index')
True
```

you will see that `index` *is* an attribute of `list`, because you can do

```
>>> list.index(test)
0
```

If you want to find out if `test` is in `list` then use `in`:

```
>>> test in list
True
```

And finally, *please* don't call a variable `list`.